# Por qué se borra el último elemento de la lista y no de acuerdo al índice que yo borro?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de una todo list.
Estoy en el último paso, borrar los elementos de la lista en la local storage.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
    function removeLocalTodos(todo) {
    let todos;
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
        todos = [];
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    }
const todoIndex = todo.children[0].innerText;
todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todoIndex), 1);
localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}
```

**Mi función deleteCheck es:**

```
    function deleteCheck(e) {
    const item = e.target;
//delete todo
    if (item.classList[0] === "trash-btn") {
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        //animation
        todo.classList.add("fall");
        removeLocalTodos(todo);
        todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
            todo.remove();
    }); 
}
//check mark
    if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle("completed");
    }
}
```

En teoría está bien, o por lo menos lo veo igual que el video que estaba siguiendo. Pero cuando borro un elemento, en la array de la local storage se borra el último item y no el item que yo borré. Y cuando actualizo la página no aparecen los items que se borraron de la array, pero si vuelven a aparecer los elementos que yo había borrado.
Por ejemplo, si en la página de la todo list yo cree los elementos:
a
b
c
d
e

Y borro b y d, en la array se borran d y e. Cuando actualizo la página aparecen a, b y c.
¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el error?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido! Te sugiero ir depurando mediante [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log) los valores que vas obteniendo en cada paso del proceso. Por ejemplo, averiguar qué recibes en `todo`, qué hay en `todos`, y qué valor obtienes en `todoIndex`. Tras revisar los datos, nos cuentas. Saludos!

Comment: Si te borra siempre el último, entonces, el `indexOf` está retornando -1 (no encontrado) y -1 para el splice le dice que empice por el final.

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, lo raro es que en el código dice todo.children[0].innerText , entonces por qué tomaría -1? O no es de ahí que me está tomando el index? Y tenés idea cómo podría corregir para que tome el index de lo que yo estoy borrando? Muchas gracias.

Comment: @quinqui probé y recibí este error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'todos' before initialization
    at removeLocalTodos (app.js:136)
    at HTMLUListElement.deleteCheck (app.js:51)                                                                 Acabo de poner en el código la función deleteCheck para que puedas ver cómo está hecha. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías averiguar en que línea del código corresponde la nº136, que es donde te salta el mensaje de error? ¿Será en esta tal vez `if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null)` ? Si así fuera, tal vez no sea `null` el valor apropiado a comparar, sino `undefined`... Son ideas.

Comment: @quinqui no, en realidad ese corresponde a console.log(todos); que agregué para ver si me mostraba algún error. Y en la línea 51 lo que hay es: removeLocalTodos(todo);

Comment: Recuerda que cuando usas variables dentro `console.log()` , debes hacerlo después de que ellas hayan sido declaradas. Si pusiste `console.log()` antes de `let todos;` , muévelo a una línea posterior a dicha declaración.

Comment: @quinqui muchas gracias, era algo que no sabía. Voy a seguir probando a ver si logro entender qué tengo que hacer.